# Nested Table Rows jQuery Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, nested, jquery-ui-sortable

I would like to sortable my nested table rows with jQuery sortable, so that it will work like a `<ul>` tag to sort.

You can have a look at it here:
http://www.studybuddy.at/

Just sign in with Google or Facebook account 
or here with

http://www.studybuddy.at/login.php
username: stackoverflow
password: stackoverflow

Hope you can help me

EDIT:
I can sort my tasks like this:

```
$("table tbody").sortable(
        {
            helper:fixHelper,
            cancel: "[t_parent='0'],#new_task_row,#date_grid_days,[t_edit='0'],.sub_task_leading_div",
            //items: "tr not:(#new_task_row)",
            handle: ".task",
            revert: true,
            delay: 200,
            axis:'y',
            cursor: 'crosshair',
            change: function(event, ui) {
                function here...
            }

        }).disableSelection()
```

but the problem is that I can't sort it like an unordered list (so that all child elements will be sorted too, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to understand your selectors for sortable.
But here is my shot.
Bdw nice ui!

```
var sort_a=$("table").sortable({  items: 'tr',handle:'.t_title'    });
```

and when you are adding new tr tell sortable to refresh.

```
sort_a.sortable( "refresh" );
```

Comment: It seems the sortable is not being able to attach I was able to see it using the javascript console.
Make sure you dom of table is loaded than try your script.

Comment: the script is working :) the thing is, that i can only sort one row...but when I want to sort one row WITH CHILDREN rows, that does not work, because then the sorting isn't correct anymore...you know, when you use an unordered list, its just easy because the elements are nested and so when the parent one is being dragged all children apply to this element...i hope you see the problem now better...thank you :)

Comment: Based on your dom I see that the table looks nested but its not.
All the children of a of a sub task are a row of the same table itself.
After the sorting function has been i.e.e  change: function
Your ui will have be the parent tr.
Now put some data identification like parent_id which will be the id of the parent.
Than you just do something like this
    $('tr[parent_id='+pid+']').after('#'+pid)
this way your child tasks follow your parent.

Comment: whats the best way to do this? i already have tags for my table rows like t_parent...how i can realize the "following" of the children while sorting?